# Custom post type slideshow background images to insert in a plugin

Tags: posts, customization

I have a slideshow which is populated with background images from a custom post type. Here's my code:

```
<?php
// start the loop
foreach($slider_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
// get image
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'home-slide');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery({
//              containment:"#wrapper",
                containment:"body",
                timer:5000,
                effTimer:5000,
                controls:"#controls",
                grayScale:false,
                autoStart:true,         

                images:[
                    "<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?> "
                ],

            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

This code displays just one slide image and not all the slide's images!

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't think your script should be inside the foreach, but that the foreach should be inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `foreach` into the script tag, as such :

In the `images` parameter of your javascript :

```
 //[...]
 images:[
      <?php

      foreach( $slider_posts as $post )
      {

      $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'home-slide');

      echo '"' . $thumb[0] . '",'; //Assuming images are separated by a comma

      }          

      ?>
 ]
```

You may need to alter the example a bit to get it working properly.

**Meta Example**

```
 foreach( $slider_posts as $post )
 {
      $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the-meta-field-name', true ); //replace true with false if you want an array of meta field results
 }
```

Comment: GREAT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  is working!!! THANKS Shane!

Comment: No problem. Could you just accept the answer so the question can appear as resolved.

Comment: just last question: To add  post meta data from custom field fo each slide?

Comment: inside the foreach, use `get_post_meta` function. I'll add an example. Codex link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: sorry !thi code is correct to have a slideshow with text (with meta field)?? thanks!                                       <?php

      foreach( $slider_posts as $post )
      {

      $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'home-slide');
      $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the-meta-field-name', true ); 

      echo '"' . $thumb[0] . '",' echo '"' .  $meta[0] . '",'; //Assuming images are separated by a comma


      }          

      ?>

Comment: You're asking if your code is correct? Did you try it out? If the code in your comment is what you have, I don't think it will work. You have to replace `'the-meta-field-name'` with the name of your meta field, and change `$meta[0]` to `$meta`, since you supplied `true` to `get_post_meta` it won't return an array, but a single value.